# Pchart 2.0 large data description

Tags: pchart

I have a bar chart, I want to show a description in the abscissa instead of the value of each bar. The description is very large and I want to know how to set a width for that description.

This is what I'm getting
[image]

And this is what I want
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to do this, just add "\n" where you need to break the string. I hope this help other people. If anybody know a better way to do it, add comments :)